# How to get a message system to connect with my GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

Im coding in java, and am a beginer, i have a code where there will be a message system, however I have the GUI in a different class, I have files: mainFrame which has all the GUI elements and is the main part of the code which initialises the different files. Server2 and Client2 which are the communication system that i got online, from this tutuorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/establishing-the-two-way-communication-between-server-and-client-in-java/
I want to be able to display the messages sent into a GUI box, however I am unsure of how to even call the classes and get them to connect to the mainframe, and after that I would like to know how to display the messages.

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k7wt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YShnP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRS8M.png)
those are the images of the code i have to initialise the entered programming,  in the image of the change page I want to have it so it will initialise communication when it is updated, and then i want to have it displayed in the text box present in the other image. However i currently only have it texting from the command window and also that it is not linked to the mainframe at all.

I am new to Stack Overflow and Java so sorry if my request makes no sence or is basic.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: As stated, please do not post images of text. It is far more useful to add a code block into your question containing your code so viewers might copy/paste your code for testing and/or amendments when providing you an answer.